# Closest fixed point to a convex set

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Consider the compact convex sets $Y \subset X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and a Lipschitz continuous function $f : X \rightarrow X$.

Assume that $f$ has multiple fixed points. (From [Brouwer's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem), $f$ has at least one [fixed point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_(mathematics)) in $X$.)

Under reasonable assumptions on $f$, which fixed point iteration converge to the fixed point of $f$ that is (among) the closest to $Y$?

(Partial/Approximate Answers and/or Hints are also OK!)

Comment: I cannot imagine any kind of non-tautological general answer to this question. Consider, for example, the case where $Y$ is a point.

Comment: This is a good point. Thanks for spotting it up.

Comment: Ok, I will change the question, hoping for non-tautological answers.

Comment: Still waaay too broad

Comment: Can you please help me refining the question then? I know that there are splitting methods to find a fixed point inside a set, if there exists one. However, I do not know what happens if there are no fixed points inside the set.

Comment: Guess you may try to start regular iteration $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ from a point $x_0\in Y$ to obtain a fixed point close to $Y$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is going to work only if $f$ is contractive and its unique fixed point is inside $Y$.